# How we can find the order of a class with two element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We are given the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$, the element $a=(4,1)$ of $G$, the subgroup $H=\langle a\rangle$ of $G$ and the group $G_1=G/H$.

Let $k$ be the order of the class of $(3,1)$ in $G_1$. Let $\ell$ the order of the class of $(2,2)$ in $G_1$.

Then what is $(k+\ell) \mod{5}$ ?

$$$$

Could you give me a hint how we can find the order of a class with two element?

Answer (score 1):

The size of group $G$ is $18$. Finding the order of $a$ is not difficult. Indeed, $|a|=3$ and so $|H|=3$ and then $|G/H|=6$:
$$H=\{(4,1),(2,2),(0,0)\}$$
$$G/H=\{H,x_1H,x_2H,x_3H,x_4H, x_5H\}, ~~~x_1,\cdots, x_5\in \{G-{a}\}$$ 
 Now we ask this question that: What is the least positive integer $t$ which makes $(3,1)^t$ into $H$? Since $(3,1)^1\notin H $ so it is one of $x_1\cdots x_5$. $(3,1)^2=(6,3)\notin H$so it is again one of $x_1\cdots x_5$ different from $(3,1)$. Doing this way $6$ times, we find $(3,1)^6=(18, 6)=(0,0)\in H$ so $(3,1)^6H=H$ and therefore $|(3,1)|=6=k.$ So the group $G/H$ is cyclic and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Do this for another element. However, this question may have easier solution.